# Why were some emotional displays tolerated in Equilibrium?

Tags: plot-explanation, equilibrium

When Brandt captures Preston he shouts to witnesses about how the cleric has been caught etc which seems to be a clear case of pride.

Also, I seem to remember when Preston is being interviewed and is asked about the best way to get a cleric's weapon off him Brandt smiles as he answers, clearly happy with himself.

If emotions are illegal then why are these tolerated?

Comment: I guess it's more of a plot-hole kind of thing, since you cannot completely hide all emotions of the actors (without drugs), which would somehow steal the substance from their play. Good question though (and maybe there's more behind it, since in your examples it's always *Brandt* who shows more emotions than usual).

Comment: Actually that is a good point, I cannot remember examples other than Brandt and we know that clerics are not above the law.  Unless Brandt was given special dispensation to allow him to bring in the traitor or something

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38807/23386.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that Brandt and Father aren't taking Prozium. They--most likely along with a small group of elites--enjoy a privileged yet secretive status with access to art, pleasure and expression. Brandt is clearly adept at hiding his emotions but cannot help but gloat when he deceives Preston, the master cleric capable of sniffing out sense offenders with only the smallest clue.

Now, why would the regular non-cleric cops tolerate these displays of emotion? First, they were only responsible for enforcing the rules of the clerics. When Preston is caught outside the city (when he rescue's the dog), the cops withdraw when they realize he's a cleric. It's not until they hear the dog that they intervene. My guess is that the mystery surrounding the clerics and their abilities makes them out of reach of the cops unless another cleric, Brandt in this case, makes the call.

Comment: That is a good point but Clerics are not above the police law, they attack and attempt to arrest/kill him.  I cannot recall exactly what was happening but they start shouting "he's a sense offender" and he takes them all out by using his gun as a melee weapon, I think a small attachement comes out of the handle which he uses.  Also how do you know that Brandt is not taking prozium?  Is it specified or are you deducing from Brandt's emotional displays?

Comment: Well, *Brandt* not taking *Prozium* would be a perfect explanation, but I don't remember this stated at any point. And if, then he wasn't officially allowed to (only inofficially by *Father*), since *Preston* had to take it, too. But it's definitely a reasonable deduction.

Comment: @Stefan - The cops called him a sense offender when they saw that he was protecting the dog. My guess is that they are given strict guidelines on how to detect offenders and would not dare to overstep those bounds with a cleric. This is based off how movies typically portray police in movies about police states.

Comment: I thought they also tried to arrest him when the resistance are being attacked? Just before they are rounded up and Brandt insists Preston orders their execution?

Comment: @ChristianRau - I can't remember the exact dialog, and I believe you're correct that it wasn't specifically stated. But the scene where Father reveals his plan to trick Preston into leading Brandt to the subversives made it seem to me that Father and Brandt were working together and not taking Prozium. I'll have to watch it again to be sure.

Comment: @Stefan - Preston was helping the resistance members escape, but I don't remember the police trying to arrest him. It was pretty clear that Brandt knew Preston was helping them and was messing with him by "allowing" him to perform the execution.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, I have to be honest - I cannot remember.  It has been years since I watched the film.  You are probably correct.